# Socket io managing multiple rooms using single socket io connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to connect to multiple rooms using single socket io connection.

I have a list of groups and each group is a room. User subscribes to the room when group is clicked.

`socket.join(group_id)`

If user subscribe to multiple groups and send message to a single group all other subscribed groups also receive the same message.

Server side Code
`socket.to(group_id).emit('message', body);`

Client Side Code

`socket.on('message', () => {});`

What can be the issue ? Why it is emitting to every other room subscribed?

Comment: can you put some detailed code?

Comment: How do you know that all other rooms get the message as well ? Normally not the room is receiving the message but the socket within. So all sockets within room `group_id` should get the message, as long the socket has joined the room.